# How to display the success message or error message in the same page using nodejs?

Tags: node.js

This code is working fine, but I have to display the message in the same page using HTML tags.

```
app.get("/home", (request, response) => {
  //Here i have to use the response.render() pass the data to  html page
});

app.post("/sub", (request, response) => {
  if (request.body.submit1) {
    let sql1 = "insert query...";
    let query = connection.query(sql1);
    response.write(
      '<script>window.alert("Applied successfully");window.location="/";</script>'
    );
  } else {
    console.log("error");
  }
});
```

I want print the success message in the same page.
`window.location` I used to redirect the page in to "localhost:8000/".

Here, I have to change html tag instead of alert message.

```
app.post("/sub", (request, response) => {
  if (request.body.submit1) {
    let sql1 = "insert query...";
    let query = connection.query(sql1);
    response.write("<h2>Applied successfully</h2>");
  } else {
    console.log("error");
  }
});
```

This is not working.
I want to display "Applied successfully" on the same page, without redirecting the page.

Comment: I would add two things here:
- if you indent your code properly, it will be much easier to understand (your future self will thank you for that)
- you might want to return something to the frontend if the insert fails.
Hope this helps too.

Answer (score 1):

You should do it on the client-side.
node is on the server, You can alternatively just redirect the client to the same page with the new data which is an old and bad solution.
Instead, just add js code to an HTML file and handle the data from the response.